The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Please try again later
I'm receiving the subject message when I test an TFDConnection to my SQL Server in Delphi.
The server is in a different AD tree. I've set up a Windows credential that seems to work, as I can connect using SSMS, and I successfully set up a DataSource in ODBC using the 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server'. I just have to make sure that the 'Trust Server Certificate' is checked.
To mimic that setting, I've added TrustServerCertificate=yes to the ODBCAdvanced setting in the FireDAC Connection Editor. I get a '...certificate chain not trusted...' error when I omit that.
I'm at a loss as to what to do next. Any ideas?


What's the connection string this wizard generates? There should be something with IntegratedSecurity i guess. Or how does your SSMS login window looks, i wonder specifically how you enter the custom domain login

I'm not sure how to find the connection string generated. The only change I had to make in SSMS is checking the box "Trust Server Certificate".

Finally resolved the issue! (Though I'm not completely happy with the solution).
After installing Delphi 12 Athens using my admin account, I tried running Delphi with my regular-access account, but there were no components, no list of Create New projects, no access to GetIt components. Though Installation help at Embarcadero assured me that any user would be able to use Delphi on my workstation after it was installed using the admin account, that was not the case.
As I result, I have been running Delphi under my admin account.  However, all of my Windows Credentials were created under my regular account. So, not too happy with Embarcadero right now.
